# Keyboard navigation (up & down arrow) for Ajax drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keyboard-navigation

I followed W3Schools tutorial on making the AJAX live search, and it has been working fine. I return my AJAX results as anchor elements.

I'd like to add keyboard navigation (i.e. up arrow and down arrow) for the Ajax drop-down, and my best result is to get the focus on the first result that stays only for a second then the focus disappears. I wonder why this focus disappears, and any way to get around it.

My JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchInput').keyup(function(e){
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (keyCode == 40){
                 $('.hint').first().focus();
                 $('.hint').first().css('color','#E8AE00'); //I can get the focus to here, but the focus will disappear right away.
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc -> load("database.xml");
    $rest = $xmlDoc -> getElementsByTagName('restaurant');

    if (strlen($q)>0){
        $hint[] = "";
        $index = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < ($rest->length); $i++){
            $name = $rest -> item($i) -> getElementsByTagName('name');
            $link = $rest -> item($i) -> getElementsByTagName('link');
            if ($name -> item(0) -> nodeType == 1){
                if (strtolower($q) == strtolower(substr($name -> item(0) -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue,0,strlen($q)))){ //if matching
                    $hint[$index] = "<a class='hint' id='hint".$index."' href='".$link -> item(0) -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue."' onfocus=\"this.style.color='#E8AE00'\">".substr($name -> item(0) -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue,0,strlen($q))."<b>".substr($name -> item(0) -> childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue,strlen($q))."</b></a><br />";
                    $index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($hint[0] == ""){
        echo "no suggestion";
    }
    else {
        for ($j = 0; $j < (count($hint)); $j++){
            echo $hint[$j];
        }
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any other methods running after keyup? it sounds as if another event listener or delayed method is taking your focus.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dropdown is disappearing because you're calling `$('.hint').first().focus();`, which steals the focus from (a.k.a blurs) `#searchInput`. Blurring the input, I assume, hides the dropdown due to some JS code that you didn't include here, which (correctly) is hiding the dropdown.

I'm not sure why you even need to call `focus()` on the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You're building the links with an inline javascript event on focus, which seems really uneccessary?

```
<a class='hint' id='hint" ...... onfocus=\"this.style.color='#E8AE00'\">"
```

also, note that you are generating the same ID multiple times? They should be unique!

If you use some jQuery and create a delegated mouse event, and then trigger that event instead of the focus event, it should most likely work ?

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $(this).css('color', '#E8AE00')
        }
    }, '.hint');

    $('#searchInput').on('keyup', function(e){
            if (e.which == 40){
                 $('.hint').first().trigger('mouseenter');
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: The duplicates is my mistake. I've been playing with the code and must have forgotten it. About the ID, I actually assign a number variable to it: hint0, hint1, hint2, ... . Though the 'onfocus' didn't have much effect to the result.

Comment: Hi Adeneo, I've tried yours. It still hasn't solved the focus problem. The focus keeps getting back to #searchInput. When I add extra line to blur the #searchInput, the focus goes to the scroll bar.